# Run a function as the Action for a DBus notification in Haskell

Tags: haskell, notifications, dbus

I'm trying to make an application that scrapes news headlines from the BBC News site, send a notification out to the users desktop when the files have been retrieved and then gives the user the option to open a window showing the titles of articles and their links. Everything is fine except the last part - I can't get fdo-notify to run an action. I'm not really sure what the syntax would be but this is what I have:

```
broadCastHeadlines = do
         client <- connectSession
         let startNote = Note { appName = "BBC News Headlines" , appImage = Nothing ,
                                summary="BBC News Headlines", actions = [], hints = [],
                                body=(Just $ Text "Latest Headlines"),
                                expiry = Never}
         notification <- notify client startNote
         headlines <- readHeadlinesFromFile
         --let headlines' = unlines $ map show headlines
         let endNote = Note { appName = "BBC News Headlines" , appImage = Nothing ,
                                summary="BBC News Headlines", actions = [(Action {actionName = "UI.main"}, "Open")], hints = [],
                                body=(Just $ Text ((getTitle $ head headlines) ++ " and " ++ (show $ length headlines) ++ " more stories.")), expiry = Never}
         headlines `seq` replace client notification endNote
```

How do I get the Action to run UI.main?

### Update

This is the link to the library repository: http://bitbucket.org/taejo/fdo-notify/

Comment: Could you provide links to the libraries in question.